# Exporting specific div classes into a dataframe

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Using BeautifulSoup, I'm trying to extract information from the following paths:

```
<div class="col-md-8 queryResponseBodyValue">2023-02-02</div>
<div class="col-md-8 queryResponseBodyValue">2003-12-26</div>
<div class="col-md-8 queryResponseBodyValue">2021-05-19</div>
```

saving this data into three separate columns in a df for each query.
The elements are shown in the figure:

[image]

I've tried this (just one field to see if it's working but actually is not):

```
total = []
exp = []
reg = []
up = []

query="www.stackoverflow.com"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(my_path)
response=driver.get('https://who.is/whois/'+x)
ex1=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-md-4 queryResponseBodyKey']").get_attribute('textContent')
ex.append(ex1)
print(ex)
```

but this doesn't identify the right elements, printing 'Name'.
The web is who.is.
The expected output would be:

```
      Ex             Reg         Up
   2023-02-02      2003-12-26   2021-05-19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong locator.
The data you are asking for can be found with this css_selector `.queryResponseBodyValue`
As well by class name `queryResponseBodyValue`
So the domain name can be get like this:

```
name=driver.find_element_css_selector(".queryResponseBodyValue").get_attribute('textContent')
```

Don't forget to add a wait before that, like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".queryResponseBodyValue"))).get_attribute('textContent')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Prophet. I think I'm still considering something wrong, since after applying your edits, I have as result 'Name.com, Inc', while I'm interested in the three dates

Comment: You can get all the 19 values there. Elements 5-7 will contain the dates. I can't locate those elements safely by any unique locator other than the key or value texts like `Expires On`. But if locating based on `Expires On` good enough for you you can use this Xpath: `"//div[contains(@class,'queryResponseBodyKey') and contains(text(),'Expires On')]/..//div[contains(@class,'queryResponseBodyValue')]"` . the same for the other dates